# DataList ItemCreated event

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, datalist

I have a datalist in my aspx page. In the datalist, there are images displayed. When I click on an image, a bigger version of the image appears in a popup, and in this popup there is a button. On that button, I want to react to a click even without postback. What I'm doing now is not working every time. I am using `go` for the `item_created` event and `__dopostback(btn.id,"onClick")`.

The `item_created` event fires when I click on the ok button on the div that displays the image.

Comment: Please state the question a bit more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that `ItemCreated` event is firing every time post back is occurring. Please do your databinding only first time when page loads. You can use `IsPostBack` property to check if it is a postback or fresh loading of page.

```
Page_Load(....){
    if(!IsPostBack){
       LoadData();
    }
}
```

If you do not want to use postback on button click, please use ajax and page methods. You can get more information here: [Using jQuery AJAX to directly call page methods](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/).

Comment: i had alredy done that data Loaddatafunction in (!ispostback ) function in page load still that problem occured